# Conditional regex on quotes and double quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, conditional-statements

I have this RegEx:

```
/templateUrl:\s*'([^']+?\.html)'/g
```

I'm trying to accept double quotes as well.
What I learnt so far is that this is the way to make conditions:

```
(?(?=regex)then|else)
```

So I would get:

```
/templateUrl:\s*(?(?=')([^']+?\.html')|(?(?=")([^"]+?\.html")))/g
```

But this is not working..what am I missing?

EDIT:

what about a giant OR?

```
/templateUrl:\s*('([^']+?\.html)')|("([^"]+?\.html)")/g
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your question with examples ?

Comment: Match single or double quote characters with `['"]`, put them in a group `()` and then match with a back reference.

Comment: Interesting I didn't think about that!

Comment: And what about the last ? `/templateUrl:\s*('([^']+?\.html)')|("([^"]+?\.html)")/g` ?

Comment: Thank you @Pointy! That works like charm!

Answer (score 1):

Atual final solution with better performance as Pointy was saying

```
/(templateUrl:\s*)(['"])([^\2]+?\.html\2)/g
```

> [abdd] is a lot faster than a|b|c|d

Final solution with **backreference**:

```
(templateUrl:\s*)('|")([^\2]+?\.html\2)
```

Previous solution (also working) with **OR**

Test [here](https://regex101.com/r/7Ags6d/2/)

```
(templateUrl:\s*)('([^']+?\.html)'|"([^"]+?\.html)")
```

Test [here](https://regex101.com/r/djwODx/1)

Answer (score -2):

You have also this the possibility which work well

`(templateUrl:)(?:\s*)(["|'](.*\.html)["|'])`

edited in order to take in count backticks

`` templateUrl:\s*([<="|'|`].*\.html[="|'|`]) ``

You will catch the `templateUrl` without the excess space the html path without quote `test.html` and the path with quote `"test.html"` or `'test.html'` or `test.html`

I hope that can help you :)

Comment: Yeah this works, but in case I wanted to add also backticks I'd have to add it twice. The other way it's enough to add it in the group, since the character is referenced later

Comment: Yep. And like I said you had to replicate the backticks in 2 spots. And still..it shouldn't match if no quotes are used. And I don't understand why templateUrl and spaces are in different groups.
And why are you using `|` inside the `[ ]` group? It's pointless..

Comment: the group for \s* avoid to get all the spaces in the case by mistake someone has added them, you right, the class [] maybe can be used the advantage of lookahead and lookbehind

Comment: As Tony says...two groups at beginning: why? You're repeating the colon and asserting it optional in the second group. Why?

Comment: ok I understood. But the url is just used to retrieve the template. Then everything is replaced with `template: {{the_retrieved_template}}`

Comment: so you need just to get the url even without the quote or backticks and you can add the quote yourself like template: \`"${the_retrieved_template}"` is that you expected ?

Comment: no, it will print backticks. It's an Angular library generator

Comment: in that case something like that can be enought no ? templateUrl:\s*([<="|'|\`].*\.html[="|'|`]) and you get just the template and the quotes